# Expansion of $\sin(a_{1}+a_{2}+....+a_{n})$?

Tags: trigonometry

We know this formula:

$$\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cdot\cos b+\sin b\cdot\cos a$$

So how to find the of the expansion of this

$$\sin(a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n})=\,?$$

Comment: $$\sin\left(\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\right)$$ solved it

Comment: $$(a_1+a_2+...a_n)-\frac{(a_1+a_2+...a_n)^3}{3!}+\frac{(a_1+a_2+...a_n)^5}{5!}+O((a_1+a_2+...a_n)^7)$$

Comment: @Shahar It is the expansion, not compression. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin(a+b+c) = \sin((a+b)+c) = \sin(a+b)\cos(c) + \sin(c)\cos(a+b)$. Now use the sum formulae for $\sin$ and $\cos$ again. Try induction after a few specific cases.

Also [wolfram alpha](http://wolframalpha.com) will happily expand these for you...